# XLookup for Range of Dates

Tags: excel

So I'm trying to create a dashboard for my monthly budget (just a fun, nonsense project). What I would like to do is have my dashboard display the bills due between today and the next 7 days. I've got a list of my bills and the day of the month they are due (ie 8 for the 8th). I've got a formula to pull today's date and then extract the day out (ie 3/14/2023 to 14), then on the next line is a formula to add 7 to the day. Here is the table I'm using:

[image]

I've tried xlookup, range, index, and I'm sure it's user error but could you help with this? Also, this will work for the first few weeks but at then end of the month the date will be 3/27 and when I add 7 it will show as 34, not 3 (as in 4/3). Maybe this is something that would work in my head but not here.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

FILTER would work better:

```
=LET(
    rng,A1:A17,
    dy,B1:B17,
    dt,E2,
    y,VSTACK(rng,rng),
    z,VSTACK(dy,dy+DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))),
    FILTER(y,(z>=dt)*(z<=dt+7)))
```

This creates a copy of the list and stacks it underneath with the second version having the dates added to the end of the month so all that will happen in the next week will be returned regardless of the day of the month currently.

[image]